# not able to remove the blank space in grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

There is a requirement like when the user enters the data in textbox and  select the value in  drop down list  and then click on search button the results will be  showing in grid .. thats working fine ... 
I have got two challenges here ..

1) I am getting empty space in kenod ui Grid in the header part like the below image shown in figure.... i have rounded it in below image(big circle)

[image]

2)   I  have got some  column names are too long in that case is there any possibility to show entire column name That I have rounded in above image (small circles) I need to display full column name in header ....

and the below code is for kendo ui grid ......

```
 <div class="GridSearch">

        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Sanmple.SampleMapp.MVC.Models.TransactionHistoryModel>()
.Name("TransactionHistroyGrid")
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Read(read => read
        .Action("Orders_Read", "TransactionHistoryResults")
        .Data("additionalData")
        )                   
 )
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.UserId).Filterable(false).Width(40);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Status).Filterable(false).Width(50);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Reviewed).Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox'  class='chkbx' type='checkbox' />").Filterable(false).Width(30);
    columns.Bound(p => p.ProjectCaseNumber).Filterable(false).Width(50);
    columns.Bound(p => p.CostPag).Filterable(false).Width(50);
    columns.Bound(p => p.ItemID).Filterable(false).Width(50);
    columns.Bound(p => p.TypeOfChange).Filterable(false).Width(50);
    columns.Bound(p => p.ChangeDescription).Filterable(false).Width(50);
    columns.Bound(p => p.CreatedOnEnd).Filterable(false).Width(50);
    columns.Bound(p => p.UpdatedOnEnd).Filterable(false).Width(50);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Comment).Filterable(false).Width(50);
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Filterable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:400px;" })   
)
</div>
```

Do i need to change any thing in kendo ui grid for these two challenges ...
would you pls suggest any ideas and any suggestions on this one...
Many Thanks in advance ....

Comment: I think its a design issue not programming.

Comment: sorry , I am not understand what you are saying is ..

Comment: @pratap k : I think the problem is with your grid `height`.2) problem please increase your column width to `.Width(140);` so you show proper column name. other then that there is no problem.

Comment: The problem is with your CSS. Check the properties on your element styles using the browser's debugging tools. As for the columns, you're explicitly setting the width on every one of them. Don't do that unless you really need to.

Comment: @Brett so, if i dint't given width it will automatically takes the width depends on column .....

Comment: Yes. If you don't define a width, the grid will size the column automatically, based on content. But, be sure you are providing enough width for all of your columns. Your current view looks cramped.

Comment: @Brett sorry i dint get the results as you said, I have removed all the column widths, I am getting same results, i am not able to see the content fully inside cell

Answer (score 0):

I have rectified my second problem with these changes that i have made to grid (just adding this property to kendo UI grid with mvc wrapper approach

```
  .Pageable()
  .Sortable()
  .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true)) // added this property to kendo UI grid 
  .Scrollable()
  .Filterable()
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:400px;" })
```